# How to use oracle11g on Docker?

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle11g

just now, i reinstall OSX on my macbook. Then i install Docker Desktop.
Because i want to use oracle database. But i encountered this logs.

`Database is not installed. Installing...
Installation files not found. Unzip installation files into mounted(/install) folder`

at first, i install SQL Developer. and in Terminal, i install jaspeen/oracle-11g by docker.

then, i run docker image.

`$ docker run -d -p 59160:22 -p 59161:1521 jaspeen/oracle-11g`

then, i typed

`$ docker ps -l`

but container's status is 'Exited (1) 16 seconds ago'

`12750f964708        jaspeen/oracle-11g   "/assets/entrypoint.…"   17 seconds ago      Exited (1) 16 seconds ago                       busy_dewdney`

if i have to install oracle database in ORACLE homepage?

Comment: How did you solved it ? What folder structure does the Dockerfile expect ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it by:

1. downloading "Linux x86-64" from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.htm
2. unzip both files into the same folder. In the end, you will have one single "database" folder where you had just unzip both files.
3. (just for the sake of the example you gave) move this folder (the "database" folder) into the "install_folder" folder
4. execute `docker run --privileged --name oracle11g -p 1521:1521 -v path/to/your/install_folder:/install jaspeen/oracle-11g` . The idea here is that the value you set for the "path/to/your/install_folder" to be the location of the folder that contains the "database" folder. In your case is it the "install_folder" folder. That *-v* flag is actually mounting your "install_folder" into docker container at "/install" location.

It will take a while until the process ends. It should first output the following:

```
Database is not installed. Installing...
Installing Oracle Database 11g
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 120 MB.   Actual 50321 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 856 MB    Passed
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2020-03-30_08-00-03PM. Please wait ...
```

When you can connect to it with credentials below, then it is up&running:

```
username/password: SYS/oracle
SID: orcl
```

Note: I had tried more than one release from Oracle's [download site](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.htm) until I found the lucky one. For example, in one situation the console just exited without any reason. When I typed `docker ps`, it showed that container exited with status 255 (which I did not find helpful).

I also found inspiration from here: https://programmer.group/install-oracle-11g-using-docker.html

Answer (score 0):

Download database installation files from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html and unpack them to install_folder. Run container and it will install oracle and create database:

docker run --privileged --name oracle11g -p 1521:1521 -v :/install jaspeen/oracle-11g

Comment: thanks. in oracle site, i will install Oracle Database 11g Release 2,
but there aren't OSX install version.

which of them should i install??

Comment: I found this blog post, with different docker image. hope it helps https://oraclespin.com/2018/03/30/docker-installation-of-oracle-database-12c-on-mac/

Comment: yeah thanks i tried to that. but it's running so slowly, probably i will have to try to another way. thanks...

Comment: How should be the folder structure look like after unpacking ? I am trying to run command, but "Installation files not found. Unzip installation files into mounted(/install) folder" comes over and over again. I have downloaded 11.2.0.2.0 zLinux64 files and unzip them into a new folder I have created and named "install_folder". It has a "database" folder inside and a lot more inside the "database" folder. It is still displaying the same error. I have also tried to move all of the files under "install_folder" directly. Still, the same ...